# Joint probability function $f(x,y)$

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

I got this question on an exam and was thrown off by the $x$ variable.

\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{cy}{x^{2}},\quad &x\geq 1,\ 0<y<1\\
0,\quad &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I understand you derive the double integral and set it equal to one but the $x$ variable is throwing me off.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state it, but I assume you seek to find the value of $c$. Recall that a PDF *must* integrate to $1$ (that's a requirement). So we simply impose that condition:
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} f(x, y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy = 1$$
We are integrating over the whole $\mathbb R^2$ plane, but using the fact that the PDF is zero on some subset of it, we can rewrite the above as
$$\int_0^1\int_1^\infty \frac{cy}{x^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy = 1$$

Now, can you finish this?

Comment: why are you doing $x^3$?

Comment: @Heavenly96 Typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

You are solving 
$$
c\int_0^1\int_1^\infty\frac{y}{x^2}dxdy=1\implies
c\int_0^1ydy\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}dx=1
$$
does that help?